# how to get public method from EventData Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, eventtrigger

I am overriding EventTrigger. How to get it from script?

[image: example]

```
public override void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData data)
{
   if (data.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("null");
        return;
    }
    if (data.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject.tag == "Field")
    {
        //HERE I WANT TO CALL METHOD, every button I have other method so I need to get it from public field

    }
    Debug.Log("OnPointerUp called.");
    GetComponent<ButtonController>().HideFields();
}
```

I don't know how to call method I set in public from overrided function. I need it because I want to use this trigger in many of buttons but every EndDrag should call other function (e.g. createBox, createSphere etc.). Best option is to set it by public, but don't know how to access it.

Answer (score 0):

I found that i should call:

```
 base.OnEndDrag(data);
```